# Wordpress Permalinks problem

Tags: permalinks

Wordpress version 4.8 (I wouldn't like to use 4.9.1 because has problem with Template page attribute )

I have big problem. I've read a lot of solution, but not works for me.

I'm creating one custom wordpress project, and on the start I have problem permalinks.

If I use "Plain" that's work fine, but if change to for example "Date and time or something else", I got this error:
[image]

I've tried to change .htaccess, but it's look ok, there is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem, there is solution:
https://webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting